# Combine elements of a list in R

Tags: r

I have a list having 2 elements with 4 columns each.

I'd like to combine 2 elements to have one element/dataframe with 4 columns and 6 rows.

Any suggestions for this?

My example, given

```
# create a list
l1 <- list(df1 = data.frame(n1 = c(2,2,0), n2 = c(2,1,1), n3 = c(0,1,1), n4 = c(0,1,1)),
           df2 = data.frame(n1 = c(1,6,0), n2 = c(2,1,8), n3 = c(0,2,1), n4 = c(0,7,1)))
```

Comment: `do.call(rbind, l1)`. This is probably a duplicate.

Comment: yes, I just tried `do.call("rbind", l1)`, it seems to be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `bind_rows` from `dplyr`, here an example with your data:

```
# Data

l1 <- list(df1 = data.frame(n1 = c(2,2,0), n2 = c(2,1,1), n3 = c(0,1,1), n4 = c(0,1,1)),
           df2 = data.frame(n1 = c(1,6,0), n2 = c(2,1,8), n3 = c(0,2,1), n4 = c(0,7,1))) 


library(dplyr)

bind_rows(l1)

  n1 n2 n3 n4
1  2  2  0  0
2  2  1  1  1
3  0  1  1  1
4  1  2  0  0
5  6  1  2  7
6  0  8  1  1
```